# UNION in WHERE clause of update subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, correlated-subquery

Are there any reasons why UNIONs shouldn't be used in the WHERE clause of update subqueries?  Or for that matter, even normal select subqueries?

Is there a better way such a query to eliminate the UNION?

Note that for my case, the UNION will result in a fairly small number of records.

```
UPDATE mytable
set mytable.bla='xxx'
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t3.t1_id=t2.id
    WHERE t2.id IN (1,2,3) AND t3.id IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM t4
    INNER JOIN t5 ON t5.id=t4.t5_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t6 ON t6.t5_id=t5.id
    WHERE t5.parent_id IN (1,2,3) AND t6.id IS NULL
);
```

Comment: One issue is the subquery can only return a single value when using equals -- perhaps you mean `in`.  If this query were to result in multiple records, it would error...  BTW -- I don't believe that query is correlated since it doesn't reference `mytable`.

Comment: @sgeddes  Yes, after seeing your comment, I agree it probably isn't correlated due to your reason given.  But, question remains whether I should or shouldn't be putting a query in the WHERE clause.  I thought when one does do so, one shouldn't use `IN`, but `=` as I showed.  Maybe not?

Comment: = as you showed will throw you an error while you run it, when using equals sign there must be only 1 value to compare to, in this case there would be more so the correct syntax is IN

Comment: @user1032531 -- in general the answer is it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Most of the times these types of queries can be rewritten using `joins` as I believe in your case.  There is no problem using a subquery in the `where` criteria though and no problem using `in` either (or `exists` or `not exists` depending on what you're doing).

Comment: @Yossi  What is different than http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33558?

Comment: = compiles fine. At execution time an error is raised if more than one row is returned from the sub-query. (I.e. bad programming, probably IN should be used.)

Comment: As it said there, when comparing to more then one value, use IN, when comparing to one value, use EQUALS sign. a subquery will return one value in example when you use a correlated sub query, or a filtered sub query , that will filter all results except one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching it to a join:-

```
UPDATE mytable 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id=t1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t3.t1_id=t2.id
    WHERE t2.id IN (1,2,3) 
    AND t3.id IS NULL
    UNION
    SELECT id 
    FROM t4
    INNER JOIN t5 ON t5.id=t4.t5_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t6 ON t6.t5_id=t5.id
    WHERE t5.parent_id IN (1,2,3) 
    AND t6.id IS NULL
) sub0
ON mytable.id = sub0.id
SET mytable.bla='xxx'
```

Comment: Okay, I can do that.  But why is it better?  Thanks

Comment: Depending on the version of MySQL, IN (subquery) is very slow. As your sub query returns possibly multiple rows you cannot just use = to check a value.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Will give it a bit more time, and select this as the best answer.  Thanks for the help.